# Lua 5.1.5's Makefile Produces Errors for Me

Tags: makefile, lua, lua-5.1

If I try to run the Makefile that comes with the source of Lua 5.1.5, I get the following errors:

```
gcc: error: #: No such file or directory
gcc: error: DLL: No such file or directory
gcc: error: needs: No such file or directory
gcc: error: all: No such file or directory
gcc: error: object: No such file or directory
gcc: error: files: No such file or directory
```

What do these errors mean? I would try fixing this issue myself before asking this question, but I don't know how to interpret these errors. If more context is needed, [here is the full output](https://pastebin.com/WafLzAEB).

Comment: It looks like your instance of a `gnu make` didn't parse comments correctly. Just erase everything till the end of line, starting with '#' on that line (line 51)

Comment: @Vlad Yeah, that turned out to be the issue, thanks. Were you able to tell what line it was on by the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug recorded [here](http://www.lua.org/bugs.html#5.1.5).

Just edit Makefile and remove `# DLL needs all object files`.